# cyber attacks datasets

Tags: security

Looking for attacks dataset, intrusion, binaries or anything related to Cyber attacks.

The ultimate goal is to build a visualization as a social network, will be great to have trace, route, interaction and source code of the attack ...

Answer (score 2):

I think the site on Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures can suite your problem: http://cve.mitre.org/data/downloads/. Lot of CVEs can be found on open source projects (like on GitHub). In those cases you can map the projects to the vulnerabilities. You can obtain binaries from those projects.

Also https://cwe.mitre.org/data/downloads.html is a valuable source.

See also https://github.com/offensive-security/exploit-database for a database of exploits. The description contains a link that redirect to the project's homepage in which you can find all the necessary information.